# Elasticsearch how sum values after aggregation result

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene, aggregate, aggregation

I have a lot of documents as below under Elasticsearch index:

```
{
        "_index": "f2016-07-17",
        "_type": "trkvjadsreqpxl.gif",
        "_id": "AVX2N3dl5siG6SyfyIjb",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "time": "1468714676424",
          "meta": {
            "cb_id": 25681,
            "mt_id": 649,
            "c_id": 1592,
            "revenue": 2.5,
            "mt_name": "GMS-INAPP-EN-2.5",
            "c_description": "COULL-INAPP-EN-2.5",
            "domain": "wv.inner-active.mobi",
            "master_domain": "649###wv.inner-active.mobi",
            "child_domain": "1592###wv.inner-active.mobi",
            "combo_domain": "25681###wv.inner-active.mobi",
            "ip": "52.42.87.73"
          }
        }
      }
```

I want to make date histogram/range aggregation on multiple fields and store the result in other collection/index.
So I could make doc_count sum using query/aggregation between hours range.

The Aggregation is:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "hour":{
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "time",
        "interval": "hour"
      },
      "aggs":{
            "hourly_M_TAG":{
               "terms":{
                  "field":"meta.mt_id"
               }
            }
         }....
    }
  }
}
```

The Result as expected:

```
"aggregations": {
    "hour": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key_as_string": "2016-07-17T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1468713600000,
          "doc_count": 94411750,
          "hourly_M_TAG": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 1485,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 30731646,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": 10,
                "doc_count": 10175501
              },
              {
                "key": 649,
                "doc_count": 200000
              }....
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2016-07-17T01:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1468717200000,
          "doc_count": 68738743,
          "hourly_M_TAG": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 2115,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 22478590,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": 559,
                "doc_count": 8307018
              },
              {
                "key": 649,
                "doc_count" :100000
              }...
```

Lets assume that I parse the response and try to store the Result in other Index/Collection.

## My Question

What is the best way to store the aggregated results ,
so I can make other query/aggregation that sums the "doc_count" between different hour ranges?

for example: between "2016-07-17T00:00:00.000Z" - "2016-07-17T01:00:00.000Z" want to see the total doc_count on each key

EXPECTED RESULT:

```
{
          "range_sum": {
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": 649,
                "doc_count": 300000 // (200000+100000)
              },
              {
                "key": 588,
                "doc_count": 2928548 // ... + ...
              }....
            ]
          }
        }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I might have your end goal wrong, but it seems to me like you want
the total `doc_count` for each value of `meta.mt_id`, over configurable ranges of time?

If that is the case I don't think you really need to store the result of the first aggregation, you really just need to change the interval value to reflect the bucket sizes you want. If you want totals for each value of `meta.mt_id`, it might help to flip the aggregation around so you are first aggregating on terms and then on the dates:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
    "hourly_M_TAG": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "meta.mt_id"
      },
      "aggs": {
      "hour": {
        "date_histogram": {
          "field": "time",
          "interval": "2h"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will give you results for each `meta.mt_id` if you wish to get totals added for a particular time range just change the interval to reflect that.

EDIT:

There might be some smart elasticsearch way of doing this but I think I would just do it like this:

Do your original aggregation

```
foreach bucket in buckets:
    index:
        {
            "id" : {meta.id},
            "timestamp" : {key_as_string}
            "count" : {doc_count}
        }
```

You should then have an index of all `meta.id` documents with their `doc_count` at various timestamps, the granularity of the interval depends on what you need.

Then you can just do a term->sum aggregation on the new index with a range filter (Assuming use of elasticsearch 2.x) for the dates:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "filter": {
    "range": {
      "timestamp": {
        "gte": "now-1h",
        "lte": "now"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "termName": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sumCounts": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "count"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Sorry if that is still not what you are looking for, I think there are many different ways of doing this.

Comment: Mic987: I've added clearly the expected result.    I need to store the results , because the request from user could be from any hour to any hour , another issue is that i have no storage left , so I aggregate the data daily, without this aggregation after 1 day , storage space problem would occur.

Comment: I've updated my answer, hopefully it's of some use, I think there a lot of different ways you could achieve what you want.